# Remove non utf8 lines in text file

Tags: string, utf-8, notepad++, keyword

How do i remove only non utf8 keywords/lines in a text file.

eg.

```
你好
相手１２３abc
this is only abc
```

I only want to remove lines that contain all english words and not the lines with utf8 words. So in this case only 'this is only abc' will be removed. Is it possible to do it in notepad++ or do i need to write a script for it?

Comment: I don't understand. Your question title is "Remove non utf8 lines in text file" but what you actually seem to want to do is "Remove lines from a file which are all-ASCII". If that is indeed what you mean, could you correct your title, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible using the following steps;

- Open Notepad++ select the Find menu and select the last tab 'Mark', enter the regex `^(([a-zA-Z])+\s?)+`, select Bookmark Line, and click the button 'Mark All'.

  [image: Marking English only files as bookmarked]
- From the drop down menu select; Search --> Bookmark --> Remove Bookmarked Lines

  [image: Finished file]

I would also recommend making sure Notepad++ is up to date.  I tested this with version 6.3.  Marking lines is something added quite recently.

Comment: Cool, glad to help.  Mark the answer please as correct, I'm trying to clear up all the Notepad++ questions.  Many thanks.